# Scrapy crawler to follow links containing keywords

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, output

I have a scrapy webcrawler that is working really well. However, I would like to make it follow only links that contain a certain keyword or phrase.  I thought I had it figured out, but my output was not correct.

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
from webcrawler.items import SitegraphItem


class GraphspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "examplespider"
    custom_settings = {
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': '2',
    }
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/products/',
    )

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = SitegraphItem()
        i['url'] = response.url
        # i['http_status'] = response.status
        llinks=[]
        for anchor in hxs.select('//a[text()="keyword"]/@href'):
            href=anchor.select('@href').extract()[0]
            if not href.lower().startswith("javascript"):
                llinks.append(urljoin_rfc(response.url,href))
        i['linkedurls'] = llinks
        return i

    def _response_downloaded(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)    
        rule = self._rules[response.meta['rule']]
        return self._parse_response(response, rule.callback, rule.cb_kwargs, rule.follow)
```

I added the "keyword" statement in the hxs.select segment but that clearly was not correct.  I'm not sure how to get the keyword to work right.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can implement your link-filtering logic using [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml) attributes.

Otherwise, use `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`. `CrawlSpider` is only useful for the limited use cases it supports; `Spider` works for all use cases.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the difference between Spider and CrawlSpider. Can I easily modify it to Spider given the code above?

Comment: I believe completing the [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) should give you enough knowledge of `Spider` to do so, yes.